# How to protect RPi camera from ESD?

Tags: case, raspicam

It [has been told](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=47627&start=50), that official Raspberry Pi camera is very sensitive to electro static discharge (ESD). Actually camera is pretty naked, so I believe that this is true. I was working with Arduino, Beagle Bone Black, Raspberry Pi etc; without problems, but it looks that my RPi [camera died maybe because of (ESD)](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=467180#p467180), despite I touched ground before. I will work with another camera in future, so I would like to try to prevent ESD scenario.

1. Are there any cheap camera holders or boxes which could cover camera electronics?
2. What are good and easy hacks reduce this risk? My bet would be to use cardboard with rubber band.

Answer (score 1):

As far as cheap and easy hacks go, printer paper is a great static shield when you don't have access to something more conventional. It's not static-free but will do the job in most cases. I like to wrap hard drives in them when I don't have access to an anti-static bag.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a new one very day on Amazon, [keyword search for "raspberry pi camera mount"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_3_19?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=raspberry%20pi%20camera%20mount&sprefix=raspberry+pi+camera%2Caps%2C223)